# UPDATE with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hi i tried to search an answer in google but i didnt find even if im not the first to have this probleme. Excuse me if im wrong...

I want to put some value of a table in another with condition and left join.
Here is my query but it does not work and i really dont understand why,.

```
UPDATE `table1`
SET `table1`.`field1` = `table2`.`value`
FROM  `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`idt1`=`table1`.`id`
WHERE `id`='35520'
```

it says :
      #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
at line3.

if you have any suggestion ill be very happy to hear those, thanks!

bastien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it like this?

```
UPDATE `table1`
SET `table1`.`field1` = (
  SELECT `table2`.`value`
  FROM `table2`
  WHERE `table2`.`idt1`=`table1`.`id`
)
WHERE `id`='35520'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. If your flavor of SQL supports it, try:

```
UPDATE `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`idt1`=`table1`.`id`
SET `table1`.`field1` = `table2`.`value`
WHERE `id`='35520'
```

Otherwise you will need a subquery:

```
UPDATE `table1`
SET `table1`.`field1` = (SELECT `table2`.`value`
                         FROM `table2`
                         WHERE `table2`.`idt1`=`table1`.`id`)
WHERE `id`='35520'
```

Comment: The "flavor" is pretty much clear due to those dreaded backticks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, very true. I'm trying to make the answer a little more generic so everyone coming here can learn something.